# Перебор многомерного массива в PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Как в PHP перебрать массив, который содержит как простые элементы, так и элементы, которые тоже являются массивами? То есть мне нужно получить данные внешнего массива и получить данные вложенных

Comment: мб `array_walk_recursive()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function perebor($arr){
  if(!is_array($arr)) return $arr;
    else {
      foreach ($arr as $key=>$item) {
        print $key.'=>'.perebor($item);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: добавьте рекурсивный вызов для чтения вложенных массивов вглубь